# I have this error: Paragraph ended before \align was complete. What can i do?

Tags: align

Hello I have this code from LaTeX, but it didn't work? Any idea?
I would appreciate if somebody can help me. :)

```
\begin{align} 
\begin{split}
  h'(v)     &= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{3-2(v+h)}-\sqrt{3-2v}}{h}\\
  &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{3-2v-2h}-\sqrt{3-2v}}{h}\\
  &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}-\sqrt{3-2v})(\sqrt{3-2v-2h}+
   \sqrt{3-2v})}{h(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}+\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
  &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3-2v-2h-3+2v}{h}
  &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2h}{h(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}-\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
  &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2}{(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}-\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
  &=\frac{-2}{(\sqrt{3-2v -2(0)}-\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
  &=\frac{-2}{(\sqrt{3-2v}-\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
  &=\frac{-2}{(2\sqrt{3-2v}\\
  &=\frac{-1}{(\sqrt{3-2v}\\
\end{split} 
\end{align}
```

Here's the link of my work: https://www.writelatex.com/1561256wvkbwk

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: can i add a picture?

Comment: @egarro You can add it, but please complete the MWE, the snippet isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last two lines:

```
&=\frac{-2}{(2\sqrt{3-2v}\\
&=\frac{-1}{(\sqrt{3-2v}\\
```

You forgot to close the `\frac{}{}` (and there is a useless `(` ):

```
&=\frac{-2}{2\sqrt{3-2v}}\\
&=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3-2v}}\\
```

There is also a missing `\\` in the 4th line of the `split` environment.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
\begin{split}
h'(v)   &= \lim_{h\to0} a\frac{\sqrt{3-2(v+h)}-\sqrt{3-2v}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}-\sqrt{3-2v})(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}+\sqrt{3-2v})}{h(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}+\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{3-2v -2h}-\sqrt{3-2v}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3-2v-2h-3+2v}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2h}{h(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}-\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2}{(\sqrt{3-2v -2h}-\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
&=\frac{-2}{(\sqrt{3-2v -2(0)}-\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
&=\frac{-2}{(\sqrt{3-2v}-\sqrt{3-2v})}\\
&=\frac{-2}{(2\sqrt{3-2v}}\\
&=\frac{-1}{(\sqrt{3-2v}}\\
\end{split} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fix the error with your suggestion, but now i have a new error: "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> }$\hfill \endtemplate"
                                 
l.121 \end{align}

Comment: @egarro Have you put the missing `\\ ` on the 4th line of the `split` environment? By line I mean one with `&=`.

Comment: Yes i did.. Now appears this: "Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.121 \end{align}"

Comment: The code compiles fine for me. I'll edit the answer to show the full code.

Comment: Also does on writeLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how can i put a picture in the first page?

Comment: @egarro What do you mean? `\includegraphics` wouldn't suffice?

Comment: I did it but if you can see the picture that i add doesn't appear on the first page...

Comment: @egarro I would suggest to open a new question for the figure question. Do you need it on a titlepage?

Comment: Maybe on writeLaTeX the image is not uploaded. Have you tried it on your PC?

Comment: Yes i do... Can you help me with that? I think that is very simple for a new question. :)

Comment: your titlepage ends at the end of the document. That is shouldn't be. Also, there are many wrong things coming to my eye. Have your read some basic material on mathematical typesetting? I stongly advice you to do.

Comment: I really don't actually it is the first time that i use this tool, the problem is that i need finish this job as soon as possible.

Comment: @egarro The image does appear, but on the next page! Try `\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{deTemplate.png}\\[1cm]` and pay attention to @Johannes_B .

Comment: @egarro You should not `\end{document}` at the beginning of it! I've corrected some of your errors.

Comment: @Astrinus, Thank you for your help, but theres a lines in my work, what happend?

Comment: Where? On the third page? You have written outside of the align environment.

Comment: No, theres a lines on all pages, are like rectangles and squares..

Comment: What are you expecting `\usepackage{showframe}` would do?

Comment: I remove them. ;)

Comment: @Astrinus Thank you again for all your help, i am very grateful.

Comment: @Astrinus @egarro I put `showframe` there. It shows you the printable type area as well as some other stuff (header, footer, marginpar). I wasn't aware that it is *that* interactive.

Comment: @Johannes_B Can you remove the title "attention"? I need to finish this work, and i really appreciated your help but please don't write things my work. ;)

Comment: You read it, thats all i wanted, you can remove it yourself. Just make sure the operators look nice ;-)