# Aligns: missing $ inserted and other severe errors

Tags: math-mode, errors, align, overleaf

I got some fatal error from my code:

```
\begin{align}

a_{n+1}-a_{n} &= \frac{1}{n+2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+1} \right) - \frac{1}{n+1} \left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} \right) \\
& = \left(\frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \left( 1+\frac{1}{2} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{n}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} \right)

\end{align}
```

I looked through every possible reasons that make error, but still couldn't figure them out.
I have tried to find out the function available in math mode but there were none.
The first error message I am confronted with is

```
Runaway argument?
 
! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

followed by further error messages if I tell LaTeX to keep stepping through the compilation process. Could you help me to figure those errors out? Appreciate with this.

```
\begin{align}

    a_{n+1}-a_{n} &= \frac{1}{n+2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+1} \right) - \frac{1}{n+1} \left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} \right) \\
    & = \left(\frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \left( 1+\frac{1}{2} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{n}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} \right)
    
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Pretty much identical question to [Paragraph ended before \align was complete - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203020) (unrelated, the error message could be caused by missing braces too [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358924) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124764) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569400) [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204328)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems fine but I had to **remove the empty lines**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a_{n+1}-a_{n} &= \frac{1}{n+2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+1} \right) - \frac{1}{n+1} \left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} \right) \\
    & = \left(\frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \left( 1+\frac{1}{2} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{n}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} \right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know that empty line would take a quite important role. Thanks, sir.

Comment: @ToBY Especially in math stuff this is important!

Comment: @ToBY - The prohibition against empty lines actually comes (mostly) from the `amsmath` package. The `amsmath` package performs a lot of useful background work to optimize the placement of equation numbers. (E.g., if a line is too long, LaTeX will move the equation number down and out of the way, which is much better than to overprint it with math stuff.) It turns out that this background work cannot be performed successfully if LaTeX encounters empty lines while in displaymath mode. This is because empty lines trigger something that's quite analogous to paragraph breaks in text mode.

Comment: The macro `\align` should be defined as `\long\def` but it doesn't. If it were `\long\def`ed then no such error occurs. Moreover, LuaTeX has `\suppressmathparerror` register: when it is positive then `\par` are ignored in math mode. And the problem discussed here exists because LaTeX users mostly does not know TeX features. Especially: empty lines are transformed to `\par` by tokenizer: if you doesn't know about this feature then you are unable to understand the TeX error message given here.

Comment: @wipet - I don't think the correct diagnosis is as simple as the one you provide. (If it were so simple, then wouldn't the creators/maintainers of the `amsmath` package have taken your suggested remedy on board a long, long time ago?) AFAICT (and I admit that I might be wrong on this...) the root cause for `amsmath` not being able to handle the equivalent of paragraph breaks lies in the fact that it performs a two-step optimization process (first measure widths, then typeset). The facile claim that "LaTeX users mostly don't know about TeX features" seems rather specious to me.

Comment: The `amsmath` maintainers cannot do this long time ago because the `\par` is interpreted as error by TeX itself in display mode and they were inspired by this behavior. Only LuaTeX is able to ignore `\par` in display math (which is much more intuitive behavior, OpTeX does the same). But `amsmath` can be used in other TeX engines too.

Comment: Hi guys, I assume that this is an information overload for a beginner :).